# Give amount of happy numbers in a given (input) range

Tags: java

As an exercise I need to make a code that will give the amount of happy numbers* in a given range. As a test I need to insert the code in a program that checks 10 different outcomes, for every good outcome you get 4 points. I want the full 40 points and my teacher said that I need to change only a little bit in my code. So far I have this:

*A happy number is a number which eventually reaches 1 when replaced by the sum of the square of each digit. For instance, 13 is a happy number because 1^2 + 3^2 = 10 and 1^2 + 0^2 = 1

Important to know: When you end up with a 4, it is definitely not a happy number.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String st1 = scan.nextLine().trim();
        String st2 = scan.nextLine().trim();

        int min = Integer.parseInt(st1);
        int max = Integer.parseInt(st2);

        Set<Integer> happyNumbers = getHappyNumbers(min, max);
        System.out.println(happyNumbers.size());

    }

    public static Set<Integer> getHappyNumbers(int min, int max) {
        Set<Integer> out = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = min; i < max; i++) {
            if (isHappy(i)) {
                out.add(i);
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

    private static boolean isHappy(int i) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (i != 0) {
            sum += Math.pow((i % 10), 2);
            i /= 10;
        }
        if (sum == 4) return false;
        else if(sum == 1) return true;
        else if (sum !=1) {return isHappy(sum);}
        else return true;
    }
}
```

My teacher also said the mistake is in the  following part:

```
if (sum == 4) return false;
        else if(sum == 1) return true;
        else if (sum !=1) {return isHappy(sum);}
        else return true;
```

Please help :)

Comment: how do you reach the last else?

Comment: the last else is not needed, since you care ==1 with the previous check!

Comment: I deleted  it but it gave an error...

Comment: Which error? execution or build error?

Comment: Main.java:38: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
1 error

Comment: @user16320675 you don't  *need* to do that. That might speed things up, but it is not a requirement

Comment: What happens if you add a 'return false;' at the end without the else? Maybe the compiler expects a return in all execution paths!?

Comment: I did that, I tested it and I got 36 out of 40 points. Not quite yet but close.

Comment: yes, that you will need  :)

Comment: You don't have to do a check with your last else.  ==4 is checked already, same with ==1. All others do not need to be checked anymore. Maybe that's what your teacher means?

Comment: Is there anything related to Integer range or long range of numbers?

Comment: Good question. There is supposed to be a range of  between 1 and 10000

Comment: @user16320675 the range is between 1 and 10000. Im not sure what you mean with 'how is the range defined'.

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOH, he did it. Thank you my man. I have got the full 40 points. May the lord bless you.

Comment: what was the needed change? I'm just curious....

Comment: I changed "< max" to "<=max" because the max also counted

Comment: I guess there are multiple ways to do it. He did say that but maybe he was right even though this was an easier solution.

Comment: You need to accept answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class HappyNumbersMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Lower limit (>0): ");
        String st1 = scan.nextLine().trim();
        System.out.print("Upper limit: ");
        String st2 = scan.nextLine().trim();

        int min = Integer.parseInt(st1);
        int max = Integer.parseInt(st2);

        Set<Integer> happyNumbers = getHappyNumbers(min, max);
        System.out.println("Happy numbers between " + min + " and " + max + ":" + happyNumbers);
    }

    public static Set<Integer> getHappyNumbers(int min, int max) {
        Set<Integer> out = new TreeSet<>();
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            if (isHappy(i)) {
                out.add(i);
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

    private static boolean isHappy(int i) {
        // Stopping conditions
        if (i == 4) {
            return false;
        } else if (i == 1) {
            return true;
        }

        int sum = 0;
        while (i > 0) {
            sum += Math.pow((i % 10), 2);
            i /= 10;
        }

        return isHappy(sum);
    }
}
```

Above works as expected, some notes:

1. When doing recursive functions, put stopping conditions as the first thing it checks
2. Adding some feedback to the user helps in understanding how to use your program
3. TreeSet will sort values, HashSet does not, better for display purposes
4. You should always verify user input (I did not do that, but you should)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sum == 4)
  return false;
else
  if(sum == 1)
    return true;
  else 
    return isHappy(sum);
```

Alternative:

```
switch ( sum ): {
  case 4: return false; break;
  case 1: return true; break;
  default: return isHappy(sum); break;
}
```

The break isn't needed, since the return in all control paths.

Comment: joup, another way... the maintenance is much higher with that... :)